# Regex split with multiple lines

Tags: python, regex, split

The following function which splits a string by the occurrence of a pattern doesn't work when the text inside brackets spans multiple lines:

```
import re
def header(text):
    authors = [i.strip() for i in re.split(r'\\and|\\thanks\{.*?\}', text, flags=re.M)]
    names = filter(None,authors)
    return '{} and {}'.format(', '.join(names[:-1]), names[-1])

print header(r"""John Bar \and Tom Foo\thanks{Testing if this works with 
multiple lines} \and Sam Baz""")
```

I don't know if the regex is wrong or if I'm using incorrectly the flag in the `split`function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.M` is for anchors in multi-line strings.  What you want is [`re.S`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.S), which makes `.` match newlines.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [re.DOTALL](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag:

```
re.S
re.DOTALL
```

> Make the '.' special character match any character at all, including
>       a newline; without this flag, '.' will match anything except a newline.